# Access body of Message actuactor through logic bricks

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Is there any way to get to the *body* of a message using just logic bricks?
It is possible to set the body using the [Message actuator](https://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/message.html); yet I see no way to access the body when using the [Message sensor](https://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/logic/sensors/types/message.html).

I know you can get to it using python, and it is quite useful, but is there any way to get that same data using the logic bricks?

Comment: I've never tried it, but I suspect that, in the undocumentedness of the expression controller, there exists a method to read it. But you sound familiar with python, so why not just use that?

Comment: Accessing the body of the message is specific to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way.

The reason is simple: what should happen when there are two or more messages?

There are way too much options to process a body (and several bodies). The information you could get is if an message with a certain content was received. The filter by subject already does that.

I agree the API looks inconsistent, as you can set a body without any use (without using Python). I see it as simplification, when you have a lot of simple message senders, but just a few  (more complex) listeners. I usually use the body when I have more information than the pure existence of a message (subject) can express.

Comment: such as sending the value of a property to an object in another scene...